# access my local server from my android virtual device?

Tags: android

I want to access a local server (installed on my machine ) trough my android virtual device, and i can't figure out how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make HTTP POST/GET to the server, or create simple PHP GET if the server is running any PHP script. Read more about HTTP Post/Get.

Also read how can you access localhost on your machine
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

> Also note that the address 127.0.0.1 on your development machine
>   corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface. If you want to
>   access services running on your development machine's loopback
>   interface (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1 on your machine), you should use the
>   special address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikola's answer - you should also be able to use an external ip address of your development machine.